# ASP.NET Core option dependency in constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and I'm attempting to create a resolvable class which has an optional parameter:

```
public class Foo
{
     public Foo() : this(null)
     {}

     public Foo(IValidator<FooEntity> validator)
     {
     }
}
```

I've created two constructors for this object so that if a dependency isn't found, I would assume it would just fall back to the default constructor.

However when I run my application I receive this error

> Additional information: Unable to resolve service for type 'FluentValidation.IValidator`1[FooEntity]' while attempting to activate 'Foo'

I know there is probably a way to manually resolve the construction of the Foo object. But I would prefer not to do that because I will have to do this for every class that I create without a validator.

Does anyone know how to configure ASP.NET Core DI to fall back to a different constructor if the dependency is not found?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I should of been a bit more clear before.

This Foo class I'm referring to in really a base class for a CRUD Service,  which will be used over and over again.

I'm looking for a generic solution which doesn't require me to configure each Service I create each time.

So using a lambda to resolve this is not an option,  The null object pattern seems feasible but I can't comprehend how to write a generic one in which I won't have to configure for each service

Comment: Having multiple constructors [is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Dependencies should not be optional. You should apply the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) instead.

Comment: Another option is to use the `IServiceProvider` in your class to try get the optional dependency. That way it won't block the service from being instantiated. I would try to avoid that approach though.

Comment: @juunas: You shouldn't inject `IServiceProvider` any where in your classes, except for factories (and here only if other solutions aren't an option)

Comment: @Steven my Foo Class is actually a generic CRUD service,  I'd like to use the null object pattern but is there a way to generically configure the DI so I don't have to create an null validator for each service that doesn't require one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its general behavior of Containers to resolve the constructor with the most parameters.

Basically what `AddTransient` does is the following:

```
services.AddTransient<Foo>();
//equals to:
services.AddTransient<Foo>(c=> new Foo(c.GetService<IValidator<FooEntity>()));
```

So you can register it yourself like this:

```
services.AddTransient<Foo>(c=> new Foo());
```

At this point in the startup class you should know if `IValidator<FooEntity>` has been registered. Or, if you are using reflection add this logic to your reflection code.

### Difference

The difference between the 2 options is that with the first option is that the `lambda function` to resolve the class is created on startup. + if you change the constructor no code needs to be changed elsewhere.

If you create the lambda yourself this lambda is compiled on build, so theoretically startup should be faster (I have not tested this).

#### Great mindset

A great mindset is to own the libraries you are using. In Visual studio/Resharper you can decompile source-code, or you can find the repositories on github nowadays.

There you can see the source code, you can see how the `services` parameters is 'compiled' to the IServiceProvider (see `BuildServiceProvider()` method, it will give you alot of insight.)

Also look at:

- [ServiceDescriptor](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceDescriptor.cs), Your type registration.
- [Service](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/Service.cs), the one that resolves the type.

### Solution

best way to do it is this, (sorry for psuedo code but i have no editor at hand).

```
getTypes()
    .Where(x=> x.EndsWith("Entity") //lets get some types by logic
    .Select(x=> typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGeneric(x)) //turn IValidator into IValidator<T>
    .Where(x=> !services.IsRegistered(x))
    .Each(x=> services.Add(x, c=> null)) //register value null for IValidator<T>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're answer is very clear, I'm aware I can explicitly resolve the foo type, but I'd like to be lazy because in my case FOO is a generic CRUD service,  and I'd prefer not to have to explicitly configure each Service for whether it is missing a validator or not

Comment: @johnny5 then be real lazy and just do it automatically with reflection, and log a warning for every service missing a validator

Comment: @johnny5  I added possible way to go in my answer, you could overwrite my code in answer when you have a working solution if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#registering-your-own-services) the `IValidator<T>` first:

```
  var services = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection();
  services.AddTransient<IValidator<FooEntity>, RealValidator<FooEntity>>();
  services.AddTransient<Foo>();

  var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
  var validator = serviceProvider.GetService<IValidator<FooEntity>>();
  var foo = serviceProvider.GetService<Foo>();

  Assert.NotNull(validator);
  Assert.NotNull(foo);
```

Comment: I know how to register the IValidator,  I just don't want to create one in the first place,  because some of my CRUD services don't require validation